# Irregular Gridview, first row with one colum, rest id the rows with two columns

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to implement an irregular `gridview` for my Android app. I've defined the `gridview` to show 2 columns but I need to show just 1 column at the first row. 
Is it possible using a `DataAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish this with a gridview. The adapter simple provides the data, but the view decides how to lay it out. If your requirements allow you to make the number of columns constant, then maybe you can use the gridlayout instead. I'm thinking you could try to do you layout like the google currents app.

Gridview and ListView are super useful if you have 1000's of items since it reuses views as it scrolls. If you have lots a items in your grid, then I would probably try to use the GridView or ListView to accomplish your goal. Maybe you have to get your requirement changed. Another option is to use a ListView, but sub-divide each row into 2 columns.